# fill the input but not active submit

Tags: reactjs

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jzRA4.png)

```
disabled = {!state.number || !state.password }
```

this condition is not working in reactjs with material UI.submit button continues to disable after fill input.

fill input but not the active button.

Comment: show us the code

Answer (score 0):

```js
export default function SignIn() {
  const classes = useStyles();

  const [state, setState] = React.useState(" ");

  const handleChange = e => {
    const { value, name } = e.target;
    setState({ [name]: value });
   
  };


  return (
    <Container component="main" maxWidth="xs" >
  
      <CssBaseline/>
      <div className={classes.paper}>
        <Avatar className={classes.avatar}>
          <LockOutlinedIcon />
        </Avatar>
        <Typography component="h1" variant="h5">
          Sign in
        </Typography>
        <form className={classes.form} >
          

          <TextField
            name="number"
            variant="outlined"
            margin="dense"
            required
            fullWidth
            id="contact phone number"
            label="Mobile Number"
            onChange={handleChange}
            value={state.number}
            autoComplete="Mobile Number"
            autoFocus
            inputProps={{
              type:'telephone',
                  maxLength: 10,
                }}
          
        
            phone="number"
          
            
          />

          <TextField
            variant="outlined"
            margin="dense"
            required
            fullWidth
            name="password"
            value={state.password}
            label="Password"
            type="password"
            placeholder="Password must be atleast 6 characters "
            onChange={handleChange}
            inputProps={{
              maxLength: 6,
            }} 
          />
          
            <Button
            type="button"
            fullWidth
            variant="contained"
            color="primary"
       
            disabled={ state.number && state.password ? true : false }
      
            className={classes.submit}>
              Sign In
              </Button>
          <Grid container>
            <Grid item xs>
              <Link href="Mobile" variant="body2">
                Forgot password
              </Link>
            </Grid>
            <Grid item>
              <Link href="CreateAccount" variant="body2">
                {"Don't have an account? Sign Up"}
              </Link>
            </Grid>
          </Grid>
        </form>
      </div>
      <Box mt={8}>
       
      </Box>
  
    </Container>
  );
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.0.1/angular.min.js"></script>
```

`disabled = {state.number.length <=0 || state.password.length <=0}`

1. List item

Comment: after running this code submit button continuo disable in condition after fill input then automatically enable button.but not happen

Comment: Are you sure that the state is getting updated on input changes? if it is okay can you check with this code { state.number && state.password ? true : false }

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure but it could be the problem that you are calling just state instead of this.state.
Try this:

```
disabled = {!this.state.number || !this.state.password }
```

Another problem could be that you aren't calling onChange method so your variables are actually still null.

Comment: this code is in function component not in class. please see below my code